# Finding all 3 character length substrings in a string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find all three letter substrings from a string in Java.

For example from the string "example string" I should get "exa", "xam", "amp", "mpl", "ple", "str", "tri", "rin", "ing".

I tried using the Java Regular expression "([a-zA-Z]){3}" but I only got "exa", "mpl", "str", "ing".

Can someone tell me a regex or method to correct this.

Comment: This is hammer/nail syndrome.  You have a brand new hammer (regex) and everything looks like a nail.  This is a case where regex is the wrong tool to use. Just iterate from position 0 to length-3, taking the substring at each index.  If you need to ignore spaces, build a temp string with spaces removed first.

Comment: @JimGarrison Just removing spaces won't work. You'll get the invalid results `les` and `est` in the example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Implementing Juvanis' idea somewhat, iterate to get your substrings, then use a regular expression to make sure the substring is all letters:

```
String s = "example string";
for (int i = 0; i <= s.length() - 3; i++) {
    String substr = s.substring(i, i + 3);
    if (substr.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) { System.out.println(substr); }
}
```

Comment: Apart from minor parentheses error in the if and print statement this is in my opinion the simplest correct solution thus far.

Comment: @MLD_Saturn Thanks. The idea is mainly Juvanis'; I just implemented it and added verification that it contains letters. Please at least give her/him an upvote.

Answer (score 3):

When a character is consumed in one regex, it cannot be used in other regexes. In your example, *a* is consumed in *exa* so *amp* will not be listed as output. You should try traditional iterative approach. It is easier to implement.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]){3}").matcher("example string");
    for (int i = 0; m.find(i); i = m.start() + 1) {
        System.out.print(m.group() + " ");
    }
```

output

```
exa xam amp mpl ple str tri rin ing
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using regex as follows:

1. Find the position of all matches for the string using the regex `\w(?=\w\w)`. This will give you the start index of the first character of each required sub-string.

   In this case, you would get: `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `8`, `9`, `10` and `11`.
2. Get what you need by taking the sub-strings starting from each position going upto that plus 2.

   In this case, that would mean, `my_string.substring(0,3)`, `my_string.substring(1,4)` and so on, as the begin index parameter is inclusive while the end index parameter is exclusive.