# Howto obtain all combination of 2 chars?

Tags: regex

Using regular expression howto obtain all combination of 2 characters on a string?

Example: "abcdefghi", Result: ab,bc,cd,de,ef
Using 3 chars: abc,bcd,cde,def...

I try with: `/.{2}/g` but is not recursive, only match ab,cd,ef but not bc,de, etc.

Howto make this?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a regex implementation that supported overlapping matches.  If you want to find out if the particular implementation you're using does - you'll need to give us some slight hint as to which implementation that is.

Comment: Is php, i have a big number, need separate in order (left to right) all combinations of 2 digits to lentght/2 of value to find.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18501538/finding-all-3-character-length-substrings-in-a-string ... one of the answers suggests that you _can't_ use regex here, because once a letter is consumed, it isn't available anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I match overlapping strings with regex?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833295/how-can-i-match-overlapping-strings-with-regex)

Comment: So why do you think a regex is the answer?  This sounds like a simple case of string slicing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
(?=(\w{2}))\w
```

Sample regex example [here](https://regex101.com/r/mHfAvC/1).

**Java Sample Code:**

```
public static void printVal(String str,int length)
{
    final String regex="(?=(\\w{"+length+"}))\\w";
    final Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile(regex,Pattern.MULTILINE);
    final Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(str);
    System.out.println("length :"+length);        
    while(matcher.find())
    {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }

}
```

**Sample Input:**

```
printVal("abcdefghi",2);
printVal("abcdefghi",3);
printVal("abcdefghi",4);
```

**Sample Output:**

```
length :2
ab
bc
cd
de
ef
fg
gh
hi
length :3
abc
bcd
cde
def
efg
fgh
ghi
length :4
abcd
bcde
cdef
defg
efgh
fghi
```