# Contiguous subsequences of a length

Tags: java, regex, algorithm

[What does this definition of contiguous subsequences mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988575/9251579)

I'm working in a problem but I don't understand how *contiguous subsequences* works. For example,

[Finding all 3 character length substrings in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18501781/9251579)

```
public class Subsequences {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "CCAATA CCGT";
        String ss = s.replaceAll("\\s+","");

        int n = 4; // subsequences of length

        for (int i=0; i <= ss.length() - n; i++) {
             String substr = ss.substring(i, i + n);
             if (substr.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) { 
                 System.out.println(substr); 
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> CCAA
>   CAAT
>   AATA
>   ATAC
>   TACC
>   ACCG
>   CCGT

Would anyone explain to me what this loop do?

```
for (int i=0; i <= ss.length() - n; i++) {
                 String substr = ss.substring(i, i + n);
                 if (substr.matches("[a-zA-Z]+")) { 
                     System.out.println(substr); 
                    }
            }
```

Comment: What exactly about the loop don't you understand? What do you understand?

Comment: have you tried to debug it?

Comment: If your given sequence is ```CCAATACCGT```, then you can form contiguous (uninterrupted) subsequences of length 4 just by taking 4 consecutive letters from the sequence. For example, starting from index 0 subsequence is ```CCAA```, starting from index 1 subsequence is ```CAAT```, starting from index 2 subsequence is ```AATA``` and so on.

Comment: Why do we skip a character each time. "CCAATACCGT" = CCAA, CAAT, AATA, ATAC?

Comment: I'm lost with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22148898/9251579

Comment: To get all the possibilities you have for taking four (4) consecutive (one immediately following the other) characters from a string you need to start with the first character and take four, then proceed to the second and take another four, and so on, until you are too close to the end.

Comment: Thanks all! I did it by hand and things got much clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ensures that the substring contains only letters (no spaces)